# Como hacer que un input arroje un resultado en especifico

Tags: php, html

Buenas ando haciendo una tabla ya me arroja los resultados en forma de tabla pero ocupo que me arroja ahora el resultado que yo ingrese en el input si pongo
por ejemplo  5x14 que me arroja solo eso y no me arroje toda la tablas no se si quitando el for se pueda pero me da error este es mi codigo:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tablass.css"
<html lang="es">
<head>

<title> </title>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$b=5;
$multi;
echo"<table border=1 cellspacing=0 width=200";
echo "<tr><th colspan=5> Tabla del $b </th></tr>";

 for($i=10; $i<=15; $i++) {   

    $multi= $i * $b;
echo "<tr><td align=center>$b</td>
             <td align=center>x</td>
             <td align=center>$i</td>
             <td align=center>=</td>
             <td align=center> ". $b*$i . "</td>
         </tr>";
 }
 echo "</table> <br/>";

 ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tablass.css"
<html lang="es">
<head>

<title> </title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>TABLA DEL 5 V2</h1>
<form action="tablaav2.php" method="post">
<h1>DAME 5</h1>:
<input type="text" name="valor1"><br>
<h1>DAME RANGO DEL 10 AL 15</h1>:
<input type="text" name="valor2"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Aceptar">

</form>
</body>

se me ocurrio poner esto pero da error:

    if($i==10){
         ´echo .($b * 10);

     }
     if($i==11){ 
     echo .($b * 11);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien y lo que deseas es mediante un form meter 2 números y que te devuelva resultado de multiplicar ambos, prueba del modo siguiente

> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="opera.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="numero1" >
                <input type="text" name="numero2">
                <input type="submit" value="ope">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> opera.php

```
<?php

$uno = $_POST['numero1'];
$dos = $_POST['numero2'];

echo $uno * $dos;
```

> Donde como puedes notar hago uso de un form, a través del método POST
>   envio las variables, recuerda para que PHP lea las variables deben
>   tener un name, mismo name que ocupo en el segundo archivo opera.php

Answer (score 2):

Al incrustar PHP en HTML debes utilizar y respetar los tags de cada lenguaje.

Tu ejercicio va muy bien solo que al utilizar el `.` punto es por que necesitas concatenar mas de dos valores, strings, constantes, etc.

Esta sería la correcta sintaxis para tu segmento de código en PHP

```
<?php
if($i==10)
{
    echo ($b * 10);
}
if($i==11)
{ 
    echo ($b * 11);
}
?>
```